# Get count of arbitrary mysql select statement (in PHP) without fetching entire result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I know there are various functions (in PHP or other programming languages) for getting the number of rows returned by a MySQL query result.

Unfortunately, when querying a very large table, sometimes PHP will run out of memory (for instance when running mysqli_query). Here are the requirements:

1) I know it's a select query, but that's all I know: it may be any query, involving joins, etc. I need a process that isn't query specific.

2) I want to be able to get the number of rows from the result, without fetching the result, since sometimes the result sets are quite large, and I run out of memory in PHP while it fetches the result.

3) I'd  rather not use buffered results, because I'd have to fetch all the buffered results before I get an accurate count (costly).

4) Also unfortunately, I need it to be fairly agnostic to what API (e.g. pdo, mysqli, etc.) is used to fetch the results in PHP since I allow in the app for people to choose which API they'll use.

Thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't COUNT() do exactly this?

Comment: `*_num_rows()` maybe? Exactly what its for.

Comment: @Amal, I know I can do, say "select count(*) from table", but I'd have to do a lot of parsing on the query to include any possible joins, where statements, having statements, etc.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, as far as I know, you need the result before you can use those functions (it dies when fetching the result)

Comment: You need the result yes.  You cant count rows without executing the query.  You dont need to "fetch" the rows to use num_rows.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: num_rows() is usually used confirm that more than zero rows were returned and continue on in that case. The whole resultset will have to be loaded for the count to be calculated. COUNT(*) is better, and faster.

Comment: @AmalMurali: OP states they dont know what the queries will be so how can they magically insert COUNT() into the query?

Comment: You can just wrap... *^W*. See [Ollie's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34362483/1438393)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take any valid SELECT-type query in any RDMS and wrap it in this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows
  FROM (
         /*arbitrary query */
       ) c
```

It will mostly work. Some RDMSs will protest if you wrap up a query using a LIMIT clause like this.

This returns a one-row resultset containing the row count. Most RDMSs optimize this kind of thing appropriately.

You could use num_rows in your client API. But if you do your RDMS will have to generate, and then abandon, the entire resultset to get that value. That is wasteful of your scarcest resources: time and space on your RDMS server. When the RDMS knows it is counting rows, its query planner can avoid shuffling any data it isn't actually going to need to just count.

Answer (score 0):

I used to solve this problem with this ***query***:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE field1 = val1
AND field2 LIKE '%val2%'
GROUP BY field3
... //other stuff
```

I recommend you to use ***PDO***, which is more secure because of its unnamed placeholder, that avoids *injection*.

So the ***query*** can be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE field1 = ?
AND field2 LIKE ?
GROUP BY field3
... //other stuff
```